# How to use shell pipeline in in libuv luv process without using sh -c

Tags: lua, libuv

Let say that I want to run the command `dmesg | rg -i hda`. How would I run this using `process.spawn` or any other asynchronous function in libuv luv and capture the output without spawning a shell with `sh -c "dmesg | rg -i hda"`?

Comment: Must you use `process.spawn` and not anything else?

Comment: I can use anything else if it allows for shell pipelines, but not spawning a separate shell.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few steps involved here. First and foremost, you will need two pipes.

The first we'll call `pipe1`, and it will be used to connect the STDOUT of the first process to the STDIN of the second process. The second, which we'll call `pipe2` will be used to capture the STDOUT of the second process.

```
local pipe1 = uv.new_pipe( false )
local pipe2 = uv.new_pipe( false )
```

Next we want to actually spawn the processes. So for simplicity's sake let's create a wrapper around LUV's spawn function so that we can focus just on the relevant function arguments.

```
spawn( "dmesg", { }, 0, pipe1 )
spawn( "rg", { "-i", "hda" }, pipe1, pipe2 )
```

The third argument is the input handle (or file descriptor) and the second argument is the output handle. Since the first process doesn't read its STDIN, then we're just passing zero for the default STDIN.

Now we're going to want to read from `pipe2` until we get an EOF. So that's simple enough:

```
local res = ""
uv.read_start( pipe2, function ( err, chunk )
    if not chunk then
        uv.read_stop( pipe2 )
        return
    end
    res = res .. chunk
end )
```

And lastly, to set everything in motion, we need to start LUV's event loop:

```
uv.run( )
```

Here's the entire code including the wrapper for spawn.

```
local uv = require( "uv" )

local function spawn( path, args, input, output )
    local options = {
        stdio = { input, output },
        args = args,
    }
    uv.spawn( path, options, function( code, signal )
        assert( code == 0, "Failed to spawn " .. path )
        uv.close( output )
    end )
end

local function read_pipe( )
    local pipe1 = uv.new_pipe( false )
    local pipe2 = uv.new_pipe( false )

    spawn( "ls", { }, 0, pipe1 )
    spawn( "awk", { [[{ print NR ": " $0; }]] }, pipe1, pipe2 )

    local res = ""
    uv.read_start( pipe2, function ( err, chunk )
        if not chunk then
            uv.read_stop( pipe2 )
            return
        end
        res = res .. chunk
    end )

    uv.run( )
    return res
end
```

For testing purposes, I used `ls` and `awk`. But those can be changed, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Try [`io.popen()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.popen):

```lua
local handle = io.popen 'dmesg | rg -i hda'
local result = handle:read '*all'
handle:close()

print (result)
```

**P.S.** I don't understand why you used `rg` rather than `grep`. Also, the filtering can be done by Lua itself:

```lua
local handle = io.popen 'dmesg'
for line in handle:lines () do
    if line:lower ():match 'hda' then
        print (line)
    end
end
handle:close ()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `io.popen()` relies on spawning a shell and I want to know if there are any ways to run a command without spawning a shell. Also, `io.popen` is synchronous and not part of libuv luv which i specified in the question.